# If a sequence of random matrices converge in probability, do their elements also converge?

Tags: statistics, measure-theory, probability-theory, random-matrices

Is it true that if a sequence of random matrices $\{X_n\}$ converge in probability to a random matrix $X_n\overset{P}{\to}X$ as $n\to\infty$ that the elements $X_n^{(i,j)}\overset{P}{\to} X^{(i,j)}$ $\forall i,j$ also, or are there additional conditions required?

I think I have proved this using the norm $\|A\|=\max_j \sum_i |A^{(i,j)}|$ and the equivalence of norms, however I have only found it stated elsewhere with the caveat that $\{X_n\}$ are symmetric or symmetric and nonnegative-definite.

Answer (score 1):

Yes: if $Y=\max\limits_{1\leqslant k\leqslant N}|Y_k|$ converges to $0$ in probability, then each $Y_k$ converges to $0$ in probability.

*Proof:* For every $\varepsilon\gt0$, $[Y_k\geqslant\varepsilon]\subseteq[Y\geqslant\varepsilon]$. QED

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Let $e_k$ be a unit basis vector with zeroes everywhere except at the k-th position. Then $\forall i,j$,
$$
X_n^{(i,j)} = e_i' X_n e_j  \overset{P}{\to} e_i' X e_j = X^{(i,j)}.
$$